# Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm getting that error, I'm new to swift and I would like to create a json out of the ARKit

```
let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
            "imageName": imageName,
            "timeStamp": currentFrame.timestamp,
            "cameraPos": dictFromVector3(positionFromTransform(currentFrame.camera.transform)),
            "cameraEulerAngle": dictFromVector3(currentFrame.camera.eulerAngles),
            "cameraTransform": arrayFromTransform(currentFrame.camera.transform),
            "cameraIntrinsics": arrayFromTransform(currentFrame.camera.intrinsics),
            "imageResolution": [
                "width": currentFrame.camera.imageResolution.width,
                "height": currentFrame.camera.imageResolution.height
            ],
            "lightEstimate": currentFrame.lightEstimate?.ambientIntensity,
            "ARPointCloud": [
                "count": currentFrame.rawFeaturePoints?.count,
                "points": arrayFromPointCloud(currentFrame.rawFeaturePoints)
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Your code should work with no problems, where is the compilation error exactly?

Comment: "ARPointCloud": [
                "count": currentFrame.rawFeaturePoints?.count,